# Cant add data to my database PSQL, column "column_name" of relation "table_name" does not exist

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm trying to add some Dummy Data to my database using the following code:

```
insert into consignment(consignment_id, consignment_type, consignment_received_date, consignment_sell_by_date, consignment_commission, album_id, client_id) 
values ('1','Album','2019-02-11','2019-07-11','10%','2','4');

insert into consignment(consignment_id, consignment_type, consignment_received_date, consignment_sell_by_date, consignment_commission, album_id, client_id) 
values('2','Album','2018-11-21','2019-04-21','10%','','4','2');

insert into consignment(consignment_id, consignment_type, consignment_received_date, consignment_sell_by_date, consignment_commission, album_id, client_id) 
values('3','Album','2019-02-12','2019-03-12','25%','3','3');
```

The first line goes in fine, then the subsequent two give the Error:

> column "consignment_received_date" of relation "consignment" does not exist.

Comment: What does your table structure look like?

Comment: `recieved` <> `received`. The column name is spelled correctly in the first two statements, but not the third one.

Comment: Can you check what are the names of existing columns?
run `\d consignment`

Comment: Please, provide us with a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Your first insert statement contains 7 columns and subsequent 7 values.  But your second statement contains same number of columns but 8 values instead of 7 but technically it should match with the number of columns. Probably you executed the statements together,  since there was a error in second statement it stopped executing the rest statements. Therefore even though your third statement was correct but it was skipped because of the error encountered.